# How to check a variable is const or not?

Tags: c#

I am willing to check if a variable is const or not. How can I do it? I Googled a lot and couldn't find a anwser.

I have a line of code: public const string xxx, in a class, and I want to check whether xxx is const or not in another class.

Comment: But , Good Programming practice is to name the constant variables in UPPER case...

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this request? Why would you want to check such a thing?

Comment: @Goron: That is not a good practice in C#.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How to check a variable is const or not?

No variables are consts. "Variable" and "const" are opposites: a variable is a storage location which can change. A constant is a value which cannot.

Can you say why you are asking the question? Likely you are going off on some wrong path; say what your real problem is and you'll have a better chance of getting a solution.

UPDATE: The question has been clarified. The question really is

> How can I tell if a member of a class or struct is a variable or a constant?

You can use reflection to tell that, like this:

- Obtain the `Type` of the class or struct via whatever technique you like.
- Obtain the `FieldInfo` of the member of the type using `GetFields`, if you do not know the name, or `GetField` if you do.
- A `FieldInfo` of a constant will have `IsLiteral` set to true and `IsInitOnly` set to false.

---

Be careful because the rules are a little bit tricky. Remember that there are three things: normal variables, readonly variables, and constants. Variables are storage locations which can change. Constants are values which cannot.  But readonly variables are variables that can change only in the constructor or initializer, and are therefore sometimes classified as variables and sometimes classified as values, but never classified as constants.

Again, it would be great if you said why you were doing this, because there might be a better solution to your real problem.

Comment: Ah, I mean I have a line of code like public const string xxx, and I want to know is xxx a const in another class

Comment: @TIANLUNZHU: Oh, I see. You wish to know if a member of a class is a constant or a variable. Yes, there is a way to do that.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused on it. FieldInfo is an array. Do you mean IsLiteral and IsInitOnly of every element of FieldInfo is true and false?

Comment: @TIANLUNZHU: Do you know the name of the field you are trying to analyze?

Comment: I am using Unity3D and I am loading some serialized data to set some fields, and I find that some fields are constant, which will generate some exceptions. I don't want to handle it by the way of exception, and I want to check it at the first place. If the field is a constant, I will not set it to the loaded data.

Comment: @TIANLUNZHU: Thanks for saying what you are really trying to do. Do you know the name of the field?  If so, then you can use `GetField`, and you will not get an array, you will just get a single `FieldInfo` for that field.

Comment: Just a pete peeve, but a "variable" is just an abstraction for a region of memory. So there's nothing wrong with "constant variable", although it does sound weird.

Comment: @giusti you start with a correct premise and deduce an exactly wrong conclusion. A variable is an abstraction of storage, yes. **A constant has no storage. It is only a value, not a location**.  That's why a constant variable is not a thing.

Comment: You can take the address of a constant. You can even cast and use a pointer to try and modify that constant (leading to undefined behavior in C; but it is not illegal because it's not a rule that constants have no storage). You can also have constant arrays.

Comment: The question is about C# not C. You can't apply the rules of C to C#.

Comment: OK, no guessing. I checked Michael L. Scott's "Programming Language Pragmatics" (4th Ed.). It says on page 115: "*In other languages (e.g., C and Ada), constants are simply variables that cannot be changed after elaboration (initialization) time."*

Comment: @giusti: In C#, a variable that cannot be changed after initialization is called a `readonly` field, and it is classified as a *variable* in the initializer and constructor, and classified as a *value* in other contexts. But in no case is it classified as a *constant*.  C# carefully defines the words "variable" and "constant". If you are speaking about C#, your best practice is to use the words as they are defined in C#; we wrote those definitions to help you speak clearly and understandably.

Comment: @giusti: That said, I would find that definition problematic. For example, is `2` a constant? Most people would agree that it is, and C# classifies it as a constant, but `2` is not "a variable that cannot be changed after initialization". That's why you've got to choose your definitions carefully.

Comment: @giusti: Also, I note that in C# you cannot take the address of a constant and you cannot construct an array of constants, and the only legal constant array reference is null.